# how to I write timestamp in erc721-contract when someone transfer it

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I want to know when the current owner has this token by storing a new timestamp every time an erc721 token is traded.
I want to store a timestamp (ex. string timestamp = "20220430") in my contract whenever transferFrom and safeTransferFrom are executed, please give me an idea of the best way.
My contract inherits from ERC721A(AZUKI standard).

Comment: Since the `transfer` methods are transactions on a contract, why not just use the [block timestamp](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9858/41739) to which the transactions are written, and save yourself some gas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to add an event:

```
event TransferTimestamp(uint256 tokenId, address from, address to, uint256 timestamp);
```

And emit it on either of the two methods, using `block.timestamp` to get the timestamp:

```
emit TransferTimestamp(tokenId, msg.sender, to, block.timestamp);
```

Note: `block.timestamp` is inaccurate. Miners are directly able to influence its value with no checks.

Alternatively, you could use the built-in `Transfer` event present in all EIP-721 NFTs. The event list has the block when it was emitted, which can then be converted to a timestamp in the DApp's frontend.